# Writing a string to the end of a file (C++)

Tags: c++, string, file, streaming

I have a C++ program already formed that has a string that I want to stream to the end of an existing text file. All of what little I have is this:

```cpp
void main()
{
    std::string str = "I am here";
    fileOUT << str;
}
```

I realize there is much to be added to this and I do apologize if it seems I am asking people to code for me, but I am completely lost because I have never done this type of programming before.

I have attempted different methods that I have come across the internet, but this is the closest thing that works and is somewhat familiar.

Comment: The `main` function returns `int`. Always. (Not my original quote.)  Return 0 or EXIT_SUCCESS to the operating system for normal termination or EXIT_FAILURE.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews This isnt the entire code... in fact, this isnt even my main function. But thanks for noting that out for me!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Open your file using `std::ios::app`

```
 #include <fstream>

 std::ofstream out;

 // std::ios::app is the open mode "append" meaning
 // new data will be written to the end of the file.
 out.open("myfile.txt", std::ios::app);

 std::string str = "I am here.";
 out << str;
```

Comment: Oh my god, that was a hella fast answer! Thanks so much!I cant believe it was that simple. But I have one question, does the ___.open("file", std::ios::app) take up a lot of memory? I am working with very large files so its very critical.

Comment: @ked: No, `out.open(..)` and `std::ofstream out(..)` only opens the handle for the data transfer. You can `open` a large file and you won't have to worry about memory unless you're actually reading the whole thing into memory.

Comment: Thanks a ton guys! Including everyone else who answered!

Comment: @ked you need to check if it's opened and do not forget to close the handler at the end : if (out.is_open()) {...;   out.close();}

Answer (score 9):

To append contents to the end of files, simply open a file with `ofstream` (which stands for *out file stream*) in `app` mode (which stands for *append*).

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ofstream fileOUT("filename.txt", ios::app); // open filename.txt in append mode

    fileOUT << "some stuff" << endl; // append "some stuff" to the end of the file

    fileOUT.close(); // close the file
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Open your stream as append, new text written to it will be written at the end of the file.

Comment: While this isn't the most detailed of answers, there's no need to downvote it, it is entirely correct and complete.

Comment: Being new, I kinda need to see the code itself, but still it was spot on thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I hope that isn't your whole code because if it is, there's lots of things wrong with it.

The way you would write out to a file looks something like this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

// main is never void
int main()
{
    std::string message = "Hello world!";

    // std::ios::out gives us an output filestream
    // and std::ios::app appends to the file.
    std::fstream file("myfile.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::app);
    file << message << std::endl;
    file.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Haha, dont worry it is not. I just had the writing to the file bit, the rest is a measly 200 lines... so far