# C++ Writing in random access file

Tags: c++, file, fstream

I'm attemping to create a random access file. Firstly, I create a file "book_data.txt" and write about 10000 blank BookType, then I want to make declear some BookType and store to file by ID but this code likely override all data in old file and just store 1 object in file each time i call saveData(). Please give a solution for this.

```
void BookType::saveData()
{
    std::ofstream bookFout("book_data.txt",std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    bookFout.seekp((getBookID() - 1) * sizeof(BookType));
    bookFout.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(this), sizeof(BookType));
    bookFout.close();
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is this relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34266112/fstream-seekp-not-working-when-the-file-is-opened-in-iosin-and-out-mode

Comment: I tried but it doesn't effect

Comment: I believe the issue is in the way you open the file check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932409/writting-a-string-to-the-end-of-a-file-c) it may help... Try changing to: `std::ofstream bookFout("book_data.txt",std::ios::app | std::ios::binary);`

Comment: BTW, seeking past the end of file on an output stream is undefined behavior.  Some platforms may pad, others may throw an exception or crash your hard drive.

Comment: show the definition of BookType

Answer (score 1):

Some notes for you:

### Don't place binary data into a "*.txt" file.

The common file type for ".txt" is an ASCII text file without control characters (except the usual line endings, tabs, backspace and maybe a few others).

Non printable characters may mess up text editors.

### Prefer not to write mirror images of classes or structures

Only `struct`s with POD members should be written *as-is*.

Classes may have v-tables and padding between members.

Some objects, such as `std::string`, may have their data located elsewhere, so you would only be writing the "control" data, not the text.

Pointers are not portable.  Your operating system may relocate your program at a different address (and the memory will be different) upon different executions.  Also, different platforms may have different pointer formats.

### Serialization

Search the internet for "C++ serialization".  What you want to do is called *serialization*.  Boost has a library for that.

If you don't want to use a library, then employ methods in your class to write individual members to a buffer or stream and read from.  This can be recursive (compound objects can call object member functions for serialization).

### Prefer not to use binary formats.

Lastly, prefer not to use binary formats.

Binary formats are hard to read in editors.

Binary formats are platform specific and may not be easily portable, see "Big Endian" and "Little Endian".

ASCII text is portable, and easy to read (which is a good thing during development).

There are human readable formats for your data, such as XML.

The usual bottleneck is not reading in a data file, since reading a data file is an infrequent operation in most applications.

### Failure is related to above

Your code snippet may be failing to one of the reasons listed above.

For example, writing an `std::string` object as-is to a file, or writing text without a sentinel character or length.